# Is it possible to make [JsonIgnore] to default and only annotate properties which I want?

Tags: json.net

**Context**

My class has many properties, and I would like to serialize only a few of them. I am aware that I can control this via `[JsonIgnore]` attribute.

**Question**

Is there any way to ignore all properties except what I annotate with `[JsonProperty]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above class:

```cs
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
```

Above any property you want to serialize:

```cs
[JsonProperty]
```

Check this [`link`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOptIn.htm) for further information.